# Visual Studio 2012 no C-Header installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have installed VisualStudio 2012 and was working for about 2 weeks with it. But now I wanted to start a C++ project (i am c# programmer usually) and I wrote some simple code. After that I wanted to compile it and I got lots of errors... there are no standart c-header files.

What I ve done:
Created a new Win32 Project (empty project)
Created code with these includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Windows.h is found the rest not. Does anyone has an idea?
I also had look at the IncludeDirectories:

```
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
```

Thats all. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Check your installation. My standard C headers are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include`. Make sure yours are too.

Comment: What is the value of `$(VCInstallDir)`?  When you go to that directory, do you see the C Standard Library headers there?

Comment: Make it - "stdlib.h", "tchar.h", <string>

Comment: @SChepurin Wrong practice! Using qoutes indicates that you provide the header. System headers must use angle brackets for distinction.

Comment: Apparently you don't have latest SDK installed. Go to C++ project settings and choose Visual Studio 2010 platform toolset, this will switch you back to SDK of previous generation, if you have it installed, that might be good enough for you. Or, of course, have proper Windows SDK installed.

Comment: @Seçkin Savaşçı: You are right. But there is a difference between what is "must" and what system can find in his case.

Comment: hmmm in the ...\VC\include directory are not my C-Header files. How can I check what is in VCInstallDir? Is this just used by VisualStudio or is that an envriorment variable? I can t go to that path using CMD or anything else

Comment: @thefiloe - This a macro. "$(VCInstallDir) -The directory into which you installed Visual C++ 2010." - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thats bad. in the include folder are just about 4 files... I am going to repair vs12 and comment here if there are news. thanks to all

Comment: no chance. everything the same

Comment: @SChepurin: Bad advice. `<stdlib.h>` is correct; `"stdlib.h"` is probably equivalent, but risks finding another header file with the same name. `<tchar.h>` is probably correct (it's not a C standard header). `<string>` is a completely different header than `<string.h>`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson - That was not "bad advice", but "quick fix". Much better at those times when all you could get was either "bad advice" or complete silence.

Comment: @SChepurin: Sorry, but it was definitely bad advice. The changes you suggested will not help, and changing `<string.h>` to `<string>` will probably cause the program not to compile.

Comment: @Keith Thompson - That was suggested to try. Your attention to 3 years old comment (if i was sure it would help, i would have written an answer) looks strange.

Comment: @SChepurin: I didn't notice the timestamp. Your defense of your incorrect comment is equally strange. Do you have some reason to think that the change you suggested might have helped?

Comment: @Keith Thompson - At this time, yes. It would not hurt, for sure. I don't defend a comment from the past (that would, certainly, look strange). I simply answer your comments. Hope you have something more productive to do in San Diego.

Comment: @SChepurin: "It would not hurt, for sure" -- That's simply incorrect. Changing `<stdlib.h>` to `"stdlib.h"` risks including a non-standard header with the same name; `"..."` does an implementation-defined search for the header file *and then* searches in the same places as for `<...>`. It's admittedly unlikely that you'd have another header file with that same name, but the change you suggested is at best completely pointless.

Comment: @SChepurin: As for changing `<string.h>` to `<string>`, those are two completely different headers (`<string.h>` defines `strlen()` et al; `<string>` is the C++ header that defines `std::string`). And thank you for your concern, but at the moment i don't have better things to do than correcting publicly visible misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you found this known issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774158/re-installed-visual-studio-2010-and-c-standard-headers-are-missing
If you install Visual Studio 2012 importing settings from Visual Studio 2010, and then uninstall it and reinstall it, the C++ standard headers are gone.

There is a solution that worked for me, proposed by Jeff at:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a987f4fa-676f-4fda-ab69-2c6bcc2684c3/visual-studio-c-2012-standard-header-files-are-missing?forum=vssetup

which entails modifying a copy of vc_librarycore.msi with orca, and then running it. That will install part of the VC folder, where the include files are (Note that modifying the original vc_librarycore.msi directly as the answer suggests did not work, probably because of permissions, so I copied the whole vc_librarycore folder to a different directory). Also note that the UUIDs used in the answer may change according to the updates applied to Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your installation, and I would recommend re-installing. I am able to use these includes just fine in my version of VS2012. Is this the Express version of Visual Studio? If so, you may need to also install the Windows Platform SDK as well.